# How to create directories automatically using ofstream

Tags: c++, filestream

I am now writing an extractor for a basic virtual file system archive (without compression).

My extractor is running into problems when it writes a file to a directory that does not exist.

Extract function :

```
void extract(ifstream * ifs, unsigned int offset, unsigned int length, std::string path)
{
    char * file = new char[length];

    ifs->seekg(offset);
    ifs->read(file, length);

    ofstream ofs(path.c_str(), ios::out|ios::binary);

    ofs.write(file, length);
    ofs.close();

    cout << patch << ", " << length << endl;

    system("pause");

    delete [] file;
}
```

`ifs` is the vfs root file, `offset` is the value when the file starts, `length` is the file length and `path` is a value from file what save offsets len etc.

For example path is data/char/actormotion.txt.

Thanks.

Comment: it's not possible with an `std::ofstream`, it's for writing files only. There's probably a good wrapper for creating directories on an arbitrary platform in `boost`.

Comment: @WhozCraig it will be hard because this archive had 20 000 files in different dirs.

Answer (score 40):

`ofstream` never creates directories. In fact, C++ doesn't provide a standard way to create a directory.

Your could use `dirname` and `mkdir` on Posix systems, or the Windows equivalents, or Boost.Filesystem. Basically, you should add some code just before the call to `ofstream`, to ensure that the directory exists by creating it if necessary.

Comment: +1 the note about C++ not having a standard way of making filesystem directories often comes as a shock to people. Nice to mention it.

Comment: thanks for this. i had no idea..battled with my code for hours trying to understand what the hell happened. i could write files for days and it suddenly stopped. Didnt realize there was another piece of code which took care of folder creation..

Comment: [A standard way to create directories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) has been added along with `std::filesystem` library in C++ 17. Currently [no compiler has supported it fully and officially](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B17_features) though.

Answer (score 19):

Its not possible with `ofstream` to check for existence of a directory

Can use [***`boost::filesystem::exists`***](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#exists) instead

```
    #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

    boost::filesystem::path dir("path");

    if(!(boost::filesystem::exists(dir))){
        std::cout<<"Doesn't Exists"<<std::endl;

        if (boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir))
            std::cout << "....Successfully Created !" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: These methods are now part of the standard and currently available under `std::experimental::filesystem`

Comment: No need for boost.

Comment: `std::experimental::filesystem` is C++17. Still need to use boost for C++11 or less.

Answer (score 7):

Creating a directory with ofstream is not possible. It is mainly used for files. There are two solutions below:

Solution 1:

```
#include <windows.h>
int _tmain() {
    //Make the directory
    system("mkdir sample");
}
```

Solution 2:

```
#include <windows.h>
int _tmain() {
    CreateDirectory("MyDir", NULL);
}
```